# Synergy: server refused client

Tags: windows, synergy, client-server

I am trying to get Synergy up and running from a new Windows 7 computer, to an XP computer. The Synergy installations seemed to go fine. I configured each to start on start-up, which they seem to, but the client won't connect. I get repeated: "server refused client with our name" messages in the log output.  The Synergy FAQ says to "Add the client to the server's configuration file." But I can't seem to find an instruction set on how to do this. I've looked and looked, but I'm lost...

Comment: Which version of Synergy are you running?

Answer (score 1):

On the new version of Synergy (1.4.2) there is a nice graphical configuration tool - qsynergy.  It's in the start menu (and also in the system tray when synergy's running).  This allows you to graphically set up the arrangement of client monitors around your server monitor.

The names you give the client monitors must match the name the client is giving the server when it connects.  This is usually the name of the computer, but can be changed in the client's configuration.